How do I create a library of my procedural materials?



I often use a simple mix shader technique to reveal a mesh. I then create node groups to keep things tidy. How do I save these so that they are accessible globally, on any new blend file? through the Shift-A menu in the shader editor window? I see a category called templates which sounds fine for this purpose.

One idea: enable the supplied add-on: "Material Library VX".  It comes with some predefined, sample materials, and you can create new categories/libraries and add materials to the libraries.  I use it extensively.

doc link

What's wrong with using Blender's built-in asset library? Link to Blender manual description and YT video on using the library including textures.

I will try both the material library vx and asset library. thanks guys
